# Como obter o valor de uma propriedade e como obter a propriedade em que está declarado o atributo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, atributos, rtti

Digamos que eu esteja criando um Atributo como esse:

```
TCompareAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
  FPropertyToCompare: string;
public
  constructor Create(APropertyToCompare: string);
  function IsValid: boolean;
end;

implementation

...
function TCompareAttribute.IsValid: boolean;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    prop := ctx.GetType(self.ClassParent).GetProperty(FPropertyToComparer);
    if prop = nil then
      raise Exception.Create('A propriedade não existe!');

    result := prop.GetValue() = ??

  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

A finalidade desse atributo é para comparar duas propriedades e verificar se possuem o mesmo valor, se estão iguais.

Tenho duas perguntas:

> 1ª. Como obter o valor da propriedade na variável **"prop"** sem a instância do objeto 
>   e;
>
> 2ª. Como obter a propriedade onde o atributo está declarado para então comparar os valores?

Answer (score 1):

Se bem entendi sua pergunta, isso vai depender um pouco da maneira como seu projeto foi modelado, pois existem N maneiras para obter dinamicamente as informações das propriedades de um objeto.

Respondendo suas perguntas:

> 1ª. Como obter o valor da propriedade na variável "prop" sem a
>   instância do objeto e;

Uma possível forma seria pelo nome da classe e propriedade via string, ex:

```
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    prop := ctx.FindType('Unit1.TForm1').GetProperty('Test1');
    ShowMessage(prop.Name);
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note que eu informei apenas o nome do form e da propriedade, ou seja, não passei nenhuma instância.

> 2ª. Como obter a propriedade onde o atributo está declarado para então
>   comparar os valores?

Na verdade seria "Como checar se um atributo está declarado em uma propriedade?", ou seja:

```
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  attr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    for prop in ctx.FindType('Unit1.TForm1').GetProperties do
      for attr in prop.GetAttributes do
        if attr is TMyAttribute then
          ShowMessage(prop.Name);
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Com isso, você pode sair do loop se a propriedade informada declara o atributo que você procura.

Segue um exemplo de como varrer as propriedades de um form, mostrando o seu nome, atributo declarado e valor atribuído:

```
type
  TMyAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FTest1: string;
    FTest2: string;
  published
    [TMyAttribute]
    property Test1: string read FTest1;
    [TMyAttribute]
    property Test2: string read FTest2;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTest1 := 'A';
  FTest2 := 'B';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  attr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    for prop in ctx.FindType('Unit1.TForm1').GetProperties do
      for attr in prop.GetAttributes do
        if attr is TMyAttribute then
          ShowMessageFmt(
            'Propriedade "%s" que declara o atributo "%s" tem o valor "%s"',
            [prop.Name, attr.ClassName, prop.GetValue(Self).AsString]);
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Espero que isso ajude! =)